# Center Content Image in Pseudo element in Div

Tags: css

I have an image in a :before element and the content image won't center.

I tried to do

```
width: 314px;
height: 176px;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
```

But this code doesn't center in on all devices...

### CSS

```
.bold_option_dropdown:before {
    content: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1595/2013/files/ENVISIONLEGGINGS-optii.png?3273);
    display:block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 406px;
  }
```

The image just centres to its parented div... [Not centred image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5o0b9.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the image as a backgound in the pseudo-element

```
.bold_option_dropdown:before {
    background: center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1595/2013/files/ENVISIONLEGGINGS-optii.png?3273);
    display:block;
    width: 406px;
    height: 406px;
}
```

Comment: Now the background still doesn't centre in the box, so this solution doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 0):

This made it, I change the element to a background as suggested and just put in one height value.

This was my solution:

### CSS

```
.bold_option_dropdown:before {
  background: center center no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1595/2013/files/ENVISIONLEGGINGS-optii.png?3273);
    display: block;
    height: 190px;
    content: '';
  }
```